# The number of 5-digit numbers of the form abcde where a,b,c,d,e belong to ${0,1,2,...9}$ and $b = a + c$, $d = c + e $ are?

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of 5-digit numbers of the form abcde where a,b,c,d,e belong to ${0,1,2,...9}$ and $b = a + c$, $d = c + e $ are?

I tried to reason out that out of the 5 digits we need to choose only $3$, that is $a,c$, and $e$, while $b$ and $d$ will become fixed on the basis of those. Now, we also need to satisfy $a + c ≤ 9$ and $c + e ≤ 9$. Solving the former equation gives us some pairs of $a$ and $c$. But, this fixes c, I cannot do the same thing with the latter equation. It just seems like a intertwined puzzle I can't get hold of from any end.

I may also add the solution given to this problem: 
[image: Solution]

I don't understand what they are trying to do here exactly.

Comment: It's $a+c\leq 9$ and $c + e \leq 9$, I think.

Comment: Why not choose $c$ first and then $b, d \ge c$

Comment: @MarkBennet You suggest drawing a tree?

Comment: Keep in mind that $a\neq 0$ or you wouldn't technically have $5$ digits.

Comment: Given a value of $c$, we can choose $b$ in $9-c$ ways ($a\gt 0$ so $c$ itself is not allowed) and $d$ in $10-c$ ways which replicates the solution given.

Comment: LOL ! are you ALLEN student ? I saw same question and same answer key in todays major test and came here !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each choice of $c$, there are $10-c$ choices for $d$ (any of $c,\dots,9$), and $9-c$ for $a$ ($b$ and $e$ are determined).  So $(10-c)(9-c)$ choices. Hence the sum.

Comment: But $a$ can't be zero , so wouldn't those $(9-c)$ cases contain cases in which $a=0$ ??

Comment: That case has been accounted for.   That's why it's $(10-c)(9-c)$ instead of $(10-c)(10-c)$.

Comment: Perhaps view it as $\sum_{c=0}^9 c(c+1)$:  $c+1$ choices for $d$, and $c$ choices for $a$.  Actually,  I think I had written $(10-c)$ choices for $a$.  It should be $(9-c)$.  I have edited.

Comment: I see , thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If $c=0$, then depending of $b \neq 9$(because $a$ cannot be $0$), $a$ could be from $1$ to $9$. And depending on $d$, $e$ could be from $0$ to $9$. So that is $9*10$ possibilities. 
For $c=1$, $a$ could go from $1$ to $8$ and $e$ could go from $0$ to $8$ for $8*9$ possibilities by similar argument.  We do this for $c=0$ to $c=9$ to get the above formula.